# Select certain part in string as variable c#

Tags: c#, string

I do have a string like the following
    "1 1/2 + 2 2/3"

Now i want the "1 1/2" as a variable, and the "2 2/3" as a different variable.
How do i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: O i am working with fractions ,and my assignment says they have to be formatted as such

Comment: @1ntello by the by, if you want these as doubles, there is going to be some additional logic to parse the individual strings. Your question is not extremely obvious as to what you need to do, and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are always going to have a '+' inbetween, you could simply do:

```
var splitStrings = stringWithPlus.Split('+');
for (int i = 0; i < splitStrings.Length; i++) {
   splitStrings[i] = splitStrings[i].Trim();
}
```

edit: If you really wanted to put these two parts into two separate variables, you could do so. But it's quite unnecessary. The type of the var is going to be `string[]` but to get them into two variables:

```
var splitStrings = stringWithPlus.Split('+');
for (int i = 0; i < splitStrings.Length; i++) {
   splitStrings[i] = splitStrings[i].Trim();
}
string firstHalf = splitStrings[0];
string secondHalf = splitStrings[1];
```

It would be *better* though, to just access these strings via the array, as then you're not allocating any more memory for the same data.

If you are comfortable with Linq and want to shorten this (the above example illustrates exactly what happens) you can do the split & foreach in one line:

```
var splitStrings = stringWithPlus.Split('+').Select(aString => aString.Trim()).ToArray();
string firstHalf=splitStrings[0];
string secondHalf=splitStrings[1];
```

If this syntax is confusing, you should do some searches on Linq, and more specifically Linq to Objects.

Comment: I should also note that this var is going to be of type string[], and you could get the "1 1/2" part via splitStrings[0], and the "2 2/3" part via splitStrings[1]

Comment: @1ntello Yes you would only have one variable, but you could put them in two different variables if you really wanted. I will edit my answer to show you.

Comment: You should reedit quite much. Can't name a variable string. String.Trim() doesn't change the value of string. Can't change the value of the enumerator variable in a foreach.

Comment: @Kevek : even though you didnt add foreach(var string in splitStrings) { string.Trim(); } its giving same thing .

Comment: I gave +1, but I have some notes: 1. naming - you get error when using string aliase as variable. 2. Trim() method returns trimmed string.

Comment: @Kevek as I've told you, you can't change the enumerator variable, otherwhise you get this on compilation: Cannot assign to 'theString' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable

Comment: :D In previous comment I wanted to add third point in notes - I hope after edit wont be `theString = theString.Trim();` in foreach loop...I should :)

Comment: Of course you're right. I should get something with caffeine before StackOverflowing

Comment: Yes happens :). Last thing change `foreach` to `for` and go get some coffee :)

Comment: +1 Because you endured. To quote PST: *(Dak'kon): "Endure. In enduring, grow strong"*

Comment: @xanatos what a wonderful game and reference. Helps ease my feeling silly for that foreach bit there ;)

Answer (score 3):

To make it shorter I used Linq to Trim the strings. Then I converted it back to an array.

```
string[] parts = stringWithPlus.Split('+').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Use them as:

```
parts[0], parts[1]... parts[n - 1]
```

where `n` = `parts.Length`.

Comment: Another abuse of LINQ and the reason I so vehemently dislike it. While a perfectly regular for or foreach loop does take slightly more code, it is infinitely more readable AND performs better.

Comment: @The Of course you can do it, and yes, it's a little abuse of LINQ. But at least the OP will learn what Linq is and will see an example. This piece of code will expose him to lambda functions. And (I was forgetting) my version worked at first shot :-) )

Comment: @The Dag why do you consider this an abuse? It's just as readable, I would argue, as long as you're used to declarative programming. It's "less readable" only because we're not all that used to the syntax, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't learn. Many Linq statements are going to be compiled to be just as performant as doing the for loop manually, as well. Unless you know differently in this case?

Comment: @Kevek Of speed I wouldn't speak, because LINQ code IS normally slower to run, but in the end on a Split this isn't a problem (it would be VERY premature optimization to think otherwise). Simply put, you need a little eye for LINQ code. You gain it after watching much LINQ code. When you gain it, you begin loathing other types of programming :-)

Comment: @xanatos I'm agreeing with you. And certainly in many cases LINQ is going to be slower, but I doubt there will be much of a difference here. There is the overhead of creating an IEnumerable and then forcing execution via ToArray, but it is not going to be so much as to be criminal. I do think that providing both "traditional" and "linq" examples together would be the most useful here, as the question is a very basic one and I doubt the LINQ would be easily understood in this context.

Comment: @The Dag: I disagree that this is abusive; I would cheerfully write code like this. I do not find code that uses *control flow* to express *sequence operations* more readable; I find it less readable. LINQ-ified code emphasizes the operations performed and de-emphasizes *how* they are performed; loops do the opposite. Your point about performance is well-taken, but remember, performance only matters *when performance matters*. Is it really likely that splitting up a short string into two shorter strings is the gating factor in a perf-sensitive application?

Comment: @The Dag: Also, don't forget that using abstractions judiciously sometimes means you can get better performance. As Joel said back in 2006: "*By abstracting away the very concept of looping, you can implement looping any way you want, including implementing it in a way that scales nicely with extra hardware.*" See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html for more.